# Trying to get thumbnail from a video by using ffmpeg

Tags: php, yii, ffmpeg

I'm trying to get thumbnail from a video , i did test this code on a side project non Yii project and it's working fine here is my action code.

```
        $ffmpeg = "C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg";
        $videoFile = $_FILES['Project']['tmp_name']['file'];
        $imageFile = Yii::app()->basePath ."/../1.jpg";
        $size = "200x200";
        $getFromSecond = 5;

        $cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $videoFile -an -ss $getFromSecond -s $size $imageFile";
        shell_exec($cmd);
```

This action called throw ajax by using dropzone Yii extension.

```
   $imageFile = "E:\xampp\htdocs\tme\protected\..\1.jpg"
```

Comment: What happens if you print out `$cmd` and run the command manually?

Comment: thank you @h2ooooooo that was helpful i found my path problem